# curl in PHP to get access_token OAuth2 return error: "invalid_client"

Tags: php, laravel, curl, oauth-2.0, laravel-5

I got a problem when getting access_token from OAuth2 Server. I'm using curl in PHP to get the access_token, but it failed and return:

```
error: "invalid_client",
error_description: "Client authentication failed."
```

The strange is, if I use the curl from command prompt:

```
curl -d "client_id=f3d259ddd3ed8ff3843839b&client_secret=4c7f6f8fa93d59c45502c0ae8c4a95b&redirect_uri=http://application.dev/oauth/handle&grant_type=authorization_code&code=rZCQQBXVSQqKi2IRro1gYkSsRhyUcLsNODACjwPw" http://oauth-server.dev/oauth/access_token
```

it success and return the access_token:

```
"access_token":"fI7APDRZygrsF1BiegAQCS1yUT8vnm1LgD5bIu2U",
"token_type":"Bearer",
"expires_in":3600
```

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and here's my code to handle from OAuth Server to get access_token:

```
public function getOAuthHandle(Request $request){
    $url = 'http://oauth-server.dev/oauth/access_token';
    $code = $request->code;
    $client_id = 'f3d259ddd3ed8ff3843839b';
    $client_secret = '4c7f6f8fa93d59c45502c0ae8c4a95b';
    $redirect_uri = 'http://application.dev/oauth/handle';

    $clienttoken_post = array(
                "code" => $code,
                "client_id" => $client_id,
                "client_secret" => $client_secret,
                "redirect_uri" => $redirect_uri,
                "grant_type" => "authorization_code"
            );

            $curl = curl_init($url);

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clienttoken_post);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

            $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);

            return $json_response;
}
```

I have tried to another script from internet and stackoverflow and restart Apache and PHP, but it still doesn't work.

Is there any way to solve this problem? What should I check?

Thank you for your help and answer.

Comment: have you tried adding grant_type on curl headers ?

Comment: No. I haven't try that one. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the request on curl headers instead.

```
    $curl = \curl_init();

    \curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 600,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $clienttoken_post,
        CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true,
    ));

    $response = \curl_exec($curl);
```

Either sent the `grant_type` on headers and then `client_secret` and `client_id` as post, or sent them on headers try it out. And btw. `$request->code` should be checked before passing to curl request. And all the `url, client_secret, client_id` MUST be with in `.env` and get them through `config/services`.

Comment: I try that, but it return `error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218`. What do you mean about `$request->code` should be checked before passwing to curl? What kind of checking? Then, I have tried to set the `url, client_secret, client_id` in `.env` but is still the same. Is `config/services` is in the OAuth server, not in the client server. Because my code error on the client server not in the OAuth server.

Comment: If I must set the `url, client_secret, client_id` in the `.env` and get them through `config/services`, what is the name of the services? Is it up to me to to name the service? And how can I access them from the services? Sorry about my stupid question because I'm new in OAuth2. And thanks for your answer.